# Structure for finding many bool matches - MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I need to store, among a few other things, a fixed set of 28 bool parameters per row in a table. I'm using MySQL.

I then need to query to return when one or more specific bool values are true for a record, particularly selecting one row by id and then any other rows where they have `true` in common.

---

That seems pretty straightforward, **and I'm certain I can write the code as described above - that is not what I'm asking for here**, but I've never implemented this sort of setup.

The focus is on finding matches efficiently - but there is zero updating, and records will have a limited lifespan, eventually being deleted in batches.

---

The questions:

1. Is there a different way of storing this other than 28 separate bool columns - some sort of binary perhaps? I've not done much with binary, and zero in a database.
2. Are there any specific performance concerns with querying that many columns I should look into?
3. How does one index a table where 28 separate columns are being searched? Is it even worth trying?

Comment: This is a useful question, and has a lot of alternative ways. Why vote down? We can even use JSON in MySQL 5.7 or 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

My answers, hope it helps:

1. You can store this 28 booleans in a derivated table with refence by some kind of id and bring then with `INNER JOIN`. Probably every boolean has a name, so a row would be something like `id, name, value`.
2. No, the quantitiy of columns if not a problem, but the size of each one is. Of course, with less data returned, less network trafic.
3. If you use a second table only a single index is necessary.

If your table will be constantly updated and deleted you can execute periodically an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on them.

Answer (score 1):

Have a single `INT UNSIGNED` column for the booleans.  It can hold up to 32 flags.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id ...,
    bools INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    other columns...,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The `WHERE` for some sample queries:

```
WHERE bools = 0   -- none of the booleans set

WHERE (bools & (1 << 17))  -- at least bool #17 is set

WHERE (bools & ((1 << 4) | (1 << 9)))  -- at least bools #4 and #9 are set

WHERE (bools & (1 << 17)) = 0  -- bool #17 is NOT set
```

Counting flags

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(bools) ... -- how many are turned on

WHERE BIT_COUNT(bools) > 3  -- if more than 3 are ON

WHERE BIT_COUNT(bools & ((1 << 4) | (1 << 9))) >= 1
           -- at least 1 of bools #4 and #9 is set
```

Turn ON/OFF one bit:

```
UPDATE ... SET bools = bools | (1 << 5)  -- turn on

UPDATE ... SET bools = bools & ~(1 << 5)  -- turn off
```

The bits are numbered 0..31 when using `(1 << n)`.
For up to 64 flags, use `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

[*Bit functions*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html)

Efficiency:  The bit operators I envision will require a full table scan.  However, the way the bits are stored is more compact than any other technique, thereby compensating somewhat on performance.

There is no benefit in `INDEXing` `bools` except when it is useful to make a "covering" index.